# Viewing multiple Google Apps emails at once

Tags: google-apps-email

I'm using Google Apps for my domain and have multiple accounts which I use for different purposes (support, contact, personal, etc). I'm looking for an easy way to manage them without having to switch from one account to another or forwarding emails between the accounts. Ideally I would like some kind of way to view all the inboxes at a single screen (or unread mail). Thunderbird allows to achieve it with saved search folders but I do not really like how it looks and prefer a web based solution.

Is there anything available to easily manage multiple accounts?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the latest Thunderbird with the Unified Inbox?  It works great and shows all you accounts/emails in one shot.  I know you wanted web based, but I have found this to be the best to handle my six GA accts.

Comment: using [account colors](https://addons.mozilla.org/af/thunderbird/addon/account-colors/) extension I can easily differentiate the account too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [unifiedinbox.com](http://unifiedinbox.com) for that - they're launching in April. I've been a beta tester over the last one year. It is a great system and will do all you have asked. It is also web based, you can use it mobile + it even includes twitter and facebook messages as well. Hope this helps!

Tim

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Firefox Add-On called [Fox Splitter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fox-splitter-formerly-split-br/) which allows you to split the viewing area and display one web-page in each pane. It can get cramped if you have a low-resolution screen but if you want to see a lot at the time, this is to be expected.

Answer (score 0):

As of late 2011 Google now lets you switch between Google accounts using the 'multiple sign-in' feature described at http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=181599

(**Replacing old answer:** If you can't find what you're looking for, the second best option may be to use http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/16341 in combination with the GreaseMonkey addon in Firefox to quickly switch between your accounts.)